# css background-image cross fade

Tags: background-image, fade, nivo-slider

I am working on a site that is using the nivo-slider plugin.  The images in the slider cross-fade fine, but I want to add a background-image repeating pattern and also have that cross fade to another image pattern.  I am restricted in that I have not been able to figure out how to add these background images as html without breaking the plugin so I am using the background-image property in css to change the background but it doesn't fade, the new background will just appear.  Using css transitions does not work on css background-image and it doesn't work when I use jquery .animate or jquery fades.  The closest I've come is fading out and then in, but this is not the cross-fade that I want.  I haven't been able to find any javascript plugins to do it either.

***So basically my question is:*** does anyone know how to cross-fade when changing an elements css background-image property?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you this way. Give some code examples of what you tried to do, and thought should work, so we have more insight in your problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two layers.

1. Nivo Slider
2. Adjacent "helper" div

We're only going to create the illusion of a crossfade.

*Step one:*
Layer 1 (nivo slider) fades the new background in. After it's done fading it, the background is moved to Layer 2 and removed from layer 1. The user won't see the switch as it's instantaneous.

*Step two:*
On the next transition, fade layer 2 out while layer 1 is fading in with the new background. Once this is done, switch the background from layer 1 to layer 2, turn layer 2 to opacity 100% and remove the background from layer 1. Again, the client-side will not see the visually switch as the appearance will look the same to them.

Rinse and Repeat.